# How to insert a new row in the list group in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Typically, when working with a "List," I would employ the "Insert Row Below" function found under the "Arrange" -> "Table" properties to add a new row.

However, I've noticed that this option is absent in the List group when attempting to insert a new row. Is there something I might be overlooking?

I'm currently using version v22.1.3 on the Chrome browser. Any guidance on this matter would be appreciated.

[image: List group]

Comment: The same is discussed in [draw.io GitHub](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/3993)